# Parenthesis parsing algorithm

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, parsing

I have a input like that

`ted(military),joseph(),chandler,barney(family(parents,children(education)))`

this input shows a folder hierarchy. string ,which is in parenthesis, is subfolder of other string, which is before parenthesis.

I want to hold them in below format.

```
+ted
--military
+joseph
+chandler (nothing can be add anymore)
+barney
--family
---parents
---children
----education
```

**if there are parenthesis after a string, it means something can be add in later stage of program. but if there isn't parenthesis something can't be add.
I've made `directory` and `file` classes for this.

To solve this problem. I've done something like that;

```
string str=input; // i've hold input in a string
int index=0;    
for(i=0;i<length;i++){    
    if(input[i]==",")//there is no parenthesis, it means file
    {  
        string str2=input.substr(0,i);
        index=i+1;
        File str2=new File();
    }
    else if(input[i]=="(")//there is parenthesis it means directory
    { 
        string str3=input.substr(index,i);
        Directory str3=new Directory();
    }
 }
```

But there are problems in directory operation. This code just find the outer directory. And also I couldn't find a way to add subfolders into directory. I thought it can be recursive solution. But i couldn't make it.

Comment: See my answer to a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119121/i-want-to-create-generic-list-from-string/34123177#34123177 the code is c# but it should be a good starting point for you :)

Comment: thank you very much. I'm looking at it.